# SSH connection became unavaialble after port number changed

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh

## Background

I am running EC2 web server on AWS Amazon Linux 2 platform. I wanted to change the port number for SSH connection so that I changed the port number shown in the next section. After this configuration change, I can not login to the AWS anymore. I searched around the related questions here but I can not find the solution to fix this issue. Please give me some advice.

## What I have done

1. I Created a new EC2 instance and logged in to the system
2. I edited "sshd_config" in /etc/ssh to insert a line "Port 65256"(Port 22 is commented out).
3. To restart the sshd, I changed the directory to "/bin" and then put the following command "sudo systemctl reload sshd.service".
4. I logged out.
5. On the EC2 dashboard, I opened the security tab in corresponding EC2 instance.
6. I clicked the link to open the security group page to modify.
7. On the Inbound tab, I added the rule to allow TCP traffic from anywhere IPv4 to port number 65256 at EC2 instance.
8. At the same time, I removed the rule which allows TCP traffic to port number 22 at EC2 instance.

## What I have confirmed

1. At EC2 dashboard, the status of this EC2 instance is running and the status check is "2/2 check passed".
2. Inbound rule list at network ACL which is located in VPC --> Security --> Network ACL, there is a rule which allows all traffic at both protocol at any port number from anywhere.
3. On EC2 dashboard, public IPv4 address is shown.
4. I checked the name of pem file to log in to the system.
5. I use the following command to connect to the system at the directory where key file is located: ssh -i "hogehoge.pem" ec2-user@ec2-123-45-67-89.compute-1.amazonaws.com -p 65256

## When I try to log in after modification

I tried a few times to log in but the AWS told me "Unable to connect: timed out".

## What should I do ?

I am searching the related posts here and articles on the web but I could not find the page to fix this issue. Does anyone know the solution ? I am waiting for your advice !

Comment: I think you need to restart sshd not only reload

Comment: Thank you brushtakopo. I put a command at /bin "sudo systemctl restart sshd" after reloading command but the same error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

**You should fallow these steps:**
**Changing the SSH port number**
To change the port for the SSH server, follow these steps:

Log in to the server as root using SSH.
Open the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file in your preferred text editor (nano, vi, etc.).
Locate the following line:
Port 7822
Remember that for security reasons, A2 Hosting uses port 7822 for SSH connections instead of the default port 22.
Change 7822 to the new port number that you want to use.
Save the changes to the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, and then exit the text editor.
Restart the SSH service using the appropriate command for your Linux distribution:

**For CentOS and Fedora, type:**

```
service sshd restart
```

**For Debian and Ubuntu, type:**

```
service ssh restart
```

While still logged in as root, in a new terminal window try to log in using the new SSH port number. If the login fails, check your settings. Do not exit your open root session until you are able to log in using the new configuration.

If you have a firewall configured for your server, you must also update the firewall rules to allow access on the new SSH port:

Comment: Thank you for leaving a message anandryadav. I have 2 questions to your comment. (1) You advised me to put a command "service sshd restart". Is it incorrect to put a command "sudo systemctl restart sshd" ? (2) I read the article that configuring the security group on EC2 instance is enough to control the traffic so that firewall command is not needed to edit. Is it also incorrect ?

Comment: yes ,you can use "sudo systemctl restart sshd".  It's depending on Linux  OS.

Comment: For ssh default port 22 you don't need to edit firewall, in your case you changed the default port.